# Uncaught ReferenceError: X is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This code is being used on a Chrome Extension.
When I call the `"showOrHideYT()"` function, I get a

> "Uncaught ReferenceError:  showOrHideYT is not defined | (anonymous
> function) | onclick"

This code will search for youtube links in a page, and it will add a button (it's really a div with an event) next to the link to show the iframe with the embedded video, pretty much like Reddit Enhancement Suite. Consider the code, per se, incomplete. I just want to know what am i missing when i call the `"showOrHideYT(frameZES12345)"` function.

if needed, i can provide manifest.json.

Thanks

```
function showOrHideYT(id)
{
    var YTvidWidth  = 420;
    var YTvidHeight = 315;
    frameYT=getElementById(id);
    console.log(frameYT.style.visibility);
    if (frameYT.style.visibility == "hidden")
        {
        frameYT.style.width = YTvidWidth+"px"; 
        frameYT.style.height = YTvidHeight+"px"; 
        frameYT.style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    if (frameYT.style.visibility == "visible")
        {
        frameYT.style.width = "0px"; 
        frameYT.style.height = "0px"; 
        frameYT.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
};


// DOM utility functions
function insertAfter( referenceNode, newNode ) {
    if ((typeof(referenceNode) == 'undefined') || (referenceNode == null)) {
        console.log(arguments.callee.caller);
    } else if ((typeof(referenceNode.parentNode) != 'undefined') && (typeof(referenceNode.nextSibling) != 'undefined')) {
        if (referenceNode.parentNode == null) {
            console.log(arguments.callee.caller);
        } else {
            referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore( newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling );
        }
    }
};
function createElementWithID(elementType, id, classname) {
    obj = document.createElement(elementType);
    if (id != null) {
        obj.setAttribute('id', id);
    }
    if ((typeof(classname) != 'undefined') && (classname != '')) {
        obj.setAttribute('class', classname);
    }
    return obj;
};
/////////////////////////////////////// 



$(document).ready(function() {

    
    var vidWidth    = 420;
    var vidHeight   = 315;
    var linksSemID  = document.getElementsByTagName("a") ;

    for (var i = 0; i < linksSemID.length; i++){
        if (/id=$/.test(linksSemID[i].href)) links[i].href += "1";
    }

    i=0;
    var youTubeRegExp = /(?:v=)([\w\-]+)/g;                 
    var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;                  
    var linkArray = document.getElementsByTagName('a');     

    forEach.call(linkArray, function(link){                 
        linkArray.id="zes" + i++;                           
        
        var linkTarget = link.getAttribute('href');         
        if (linkTarget!=null)                               
            {
            if (linkTarget.search(youTubeRegExp) !=-1)      
                {
                
                console.log (linkTarget);
                idVideo=linkTarget.match(/(?:v=)([\w\-]+)/g);
                //idVideo = idVideo.replace("v=", "");      
                
                //add buton
                botaoMais = document.createElement('DIV');
                botaoMais.setAttribute('class','expando-button collapsed video');
                botaoMais.setAttribute('onclick','showOrHideYT(frameZES'+ i +')');
                insertAfter(link, botaoMais);

                
                
                //add iframe
                ifrm = document.createElement('IFRAME'); 
                ifrm.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+ idVideo); 
                ifrm.style.width = '0px'; 
                ifrm.style.height = '0px'; 
                ifrm.style.frameborder='0px';
                ifrm.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                ifrm.setAttribute('id', 'frameZES' + i);
                insertAfter(link, ifrm);
                
                }
            }
    });  

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `setAttribute` with a string, the event will be executed in the context of the page. The functions which are defined in a Content script are executed in a sandboxed scope. So, you have to pass a function reference, instead of a string:

Replace:

```
    botaoMais.setAttribute('onclick','showOrHideYT(frameZES'+ i +')');
```

With:

```
    botaoMais.addEventListener('click', (function(i) {
        return function() {
            showOrHideYT("frameZES"+ i);
        };
    })(i));
```

Explanation of code:

- `(function(i) { ..})(i)` is used to preserve the value of `i` for each event.
- Inside this self-invoking function, another function is returned, used as an event listener to `click`.

Comment: Also, even if you want to use the event as a string ,`frameZES` has to be quoted. Otherwise, the engine would look for a variable called `frameZES`, then concatenate its value with `i`.

Comment: thank you Rob W, that solved my issue. Just a little typo on your suggestion: swap the [ for a {, last char from the 1st line ;)

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using jQuery in your code. I personally think if we are using a library like jQuery, then we should not mix the native javascript code and jQuery code.
You can use jQuery bind to bind your the functions you need to call on dom ready. 
Read below to know more.

suppose you want to call a javascript function on a button click, Here is the HTML for the same.

```
<div id="clickme">
     <input id= "clickmebutton" type="button" value = "clickme" />
</div>
```

suppose "test" is the function you need to call, here is the code for test function.

```
function test() {
   alert("hello");
}
```

you now need to bind the test function on the button click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clickmebutton").bind("click", function(){
        // do what ever you want to do here
        test();
   });

});
```